# How to make input text field read-only

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-5

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="bit_app_policy_category_status">Please Insert the Code<span class="required">*</span></label>
 <input type="text" name="code" class="form-control" value="{{$category->code}}" placeholder="Enter the Code" />
</div>
```

All I want is to let the field be unable to change, but viewable only.

[image: Expected output]

[image: I WISH THE CODE COLUMN CAN VIEW ONLY BUT NOT EDIT]

Comment: use ether the diabled or readonly attributes

Comment: thanks i just added readonly behind and its working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

html has two attributes for this. `readonly` and `disabled`. when any input field has the `disabled` attribute, the value will not be editable. and the value won't pass with the form either. in case of `readonly` attribute, value will not be editable but it will be passed with the form. so use `readonly`

```
<input type="text" name="code" class="form-control" value="{{$category->code}}" placeholder="Enter the Code" readonly />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="code" class="form-control" value="{{$category->code}}" placeholder="Enter the Code" disabled />`
```

add disabled to the input.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="code" class="form-control" value="{{$category->code}}" placeholder="Enter the Code" readonly />
```

or

```
<input type="text" name="code" class="form-control" value="{{$category->code}}" placeholder="Enter the Code" disabled />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use readonly like this:-

```
<input type="text" name="code" class="form-control" value="{{$category->code}}" placeholder="Enter the Code" readonly/>
```